# Developing A Spring web-app using two different contexts

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In the [spring reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/pdf/spring-framework-reference.pdf)

section 2.3 Usage scenarios, there is a paragraph that goes like this

**Sometimes circumstances do not allow you to completely switch to a different framework. The Spring
Framework does 
not
 force you to use everything within it; it is not an 
all-or-nothing
 solution. Existing
front-ends  built  with  Struts,  Tapestry,  JSF  or  other  UI  frameworks  can  be  integrated  with  a  Spring-
based middle-tier, which allows you to use Spring transaction features. You simply need to wire up your
business  logic  using  an  ApplicationContext
  and  use  a  WebApplicationContext
  to  integrate
your web layer.**

Now I am not able to understand the last sentence. How can we wire up our business logic using an ApplicationContext and use a WebApplicationContext to integrate with web layer. How can we achieve this? And is the web-layer that they are talking about contains controllers and jsps?

As far as I remember if we needed any object in a class we simply autowire them and spring does the rest of the work.

Can someone please provide an explanation with examples. Please forgive my ignorances as I have just started to learn spring.

If a similar question is asked can someone please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, even you can create more than one different context hierarchically.

I will give both answers, both hierarchic and non-hierarchic. I'll use java based configuration for both. I will give the answer for two context but you can implement this for many context.

**1)Non-Hierarchic**

Create two different `context.xml`, assume that `context1.xml` and `context2.xml` . context1.xml should be like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns=..... some imports >

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="desiredPackage1" />

<bean id="properties"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>db.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="properties"/>
```

For context2.xml change only

```
<context:component-scan base-package="desiredPackage2" />
```

Then create a `Configuration.java` class like this:

```
public class Config {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ApplicationContext desiredContext1 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("file:////...path.../context1.xml");

        ApplicationContext desiredContext2 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("file:////...path.../context2.xml");
    }
}
```

Now you have two different context, if you want to it hierarchically, change the main method like this : 
**2)Hierarchic**

```
public class Config {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ApplicationContext desiredContext1 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("file:////...path.../context1.xml");
        String[] congigPath = new String[1];
        congigPath[0] = "file:////...path.../context2.xml";
        ApplicationContext desiredContext2 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(congigPath,desiredContext1);
    }
}
```

In this case, desiredContext2 object could see desiredContext1 object but desiredContext1 object can not see desiredContext2 object.

If you want to use it when building your web-app use this annotations with you configuration class,

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("context1.xml", "context2.xml")
public class Config { ....
```

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: This will surely help. So now if I'm autowiring any object in any class spring will search both the contexts desiredContext1 and desiredContext2 to check if the bean declaration is present in any of the contexts, is that correct?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You may setup two or even three different projects or modules each with their own context. For example a web project with WebApplicationContext which is rendering the views and calls business methods i.e. usinf restful web services from business tier. And setup a separate project or module to handle business which has its own context file and beans. And even a commons project to include shared beans between the web and business tier.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can we achieve this kind of configuration for a single project or module?